Flutter android app shows white blank screen in release mode
I have a Flutter application, it works perfectly fine when I run it in debug mode, but when I configured the signing key and everything that's needed for a release build and run it in release mode, it shows a white blank screen, what's even more weird is that there's chances it worked fine in release mode, about once out of 7-8 release install, which makes me really crazy about this issue, I have googled for solution, searched for issues in the flutter repo, tried everything I found on the web, yet I still don't find a solution, can anyone help me please!
This is my main file：
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shutiaotv_app/data/user_manager.dart';
import 'package:shutiaotv_app/presentation/splash_screen/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:feedback/feedback.dart';
import 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart';

import 'core/theme/theme_constants.dart';
import 'core/theme/theme_manager.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    const BetterFeedback(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

ThemeManager themeManager = ThemeManager();

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});


  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}


class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    themeManager.addListener(themeListener);
    UserManager().loadData().then((value) => themeManager.toggleTheme(UserManager().isDark));
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    themeManager.removeListener(themeListener);
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }


  void themeListener() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '泰美影视',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
      themeMode: themeManager.themeMode,
      home: UpgradeAlert(
        showIgnore: false,
        child: const SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }

}



This is my pubspec yaml file:
name: shutiaotv_app
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+3

environment:
#  sdk: '>=2.19.3 <3.0.0'
  sdk: '>=3.3.4 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9

  flutter_switch: ^0.3.2
  pin_code_fields: ^8.0.1
  video_player: ^2.4.6
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  country_list_pick: ^1.0.1+5
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  meilisearch: ^0.15.0
  fijkplayer: ^0.11.0
  dio: ^5.3.0
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  email_validator: ^2.1.17
  timer_count_down: ^2.2.2
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^4.0.0
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  getwidget: ^4.0.0
  expandable_text: ^2.3.0
  extended_wrap: ^0.1.5
  flutter_animated_icon_button: ^1.1.3
  animated_snack_bar: ^0.4.0
  duration: ^3.0.13
  url_launcher: ^6.2.6
  path_provider: ^2.1.2
  filesize: ^2.0.1
  disk_space_plus: ^0.2.3
  feedback: ^3.0.1
  page_transition: ^2.1.0
  upgrader: ^10.0.1
  in_app_review: ^2.0.9

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.10

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/app_icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21


flutter_native_splash:
  background_image: "assets/splash_background.png"

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700

  fonts:
    - family: SF Pro Display
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Noto_Sans_SC/NotoSansSC-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Noto_Sans_SC/NotoSansSC-Medium.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Noto_Sans_SC/NotoSansSC-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700

#        - asset: assets/fonts/SFPRODISPLAYREGULAR.OTF
#          weight: 400
#        - asset: assets/fonts/SFPRODISPLAYMEDIUM.OTF
#          weight: 600
#        - asset: assets/fonts/SFPRODISPLAYBOLD.OTF
#          weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages


This is my splash_screen file which is the home page of the material app widget:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shutiaotv_app/core/app_export.dart';
import 'package:shutiaotv_app/data/user_manager.dart';
import 'package:shutiaotv_app/presentation/home.dart';
import 'package:shutiaotv_app/presentation/onboarding_1_vone_screen/onboarding_1_vone_screen.dart';
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
        UserManager().loadUser().then((user) {
          if (user == null) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Onboarding1VoneScreen()));
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Home()), (route) => false);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ColorConstant.splashBackground,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: CommonImageView(
              imagePath: ImageConstant.tvLogo,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              width: getHorizontalSize(200.00),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 48),
              child: AnimatedTextKit(
                totalRepeatCount: 1,
                animatedTexts: [
                  TypewriterAnimatedText(
                    '泰美影视',
                    speed: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: getFontSize(48),
                      fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      height: 1.00,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}


This is the screenshot of a rare situation when it worked in release mode and doesn't show just a white blank screen.

This is the screenshot when most of the times when it only shows a white blank screen when run in release mode.

This is the project build.gradle file:
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

This is the app build.gradle file:
    plugins {
  id "com.android.application"
  id "kotlin-android"
  id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
  localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
  }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
  flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
  flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
  keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
  ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
  }

  sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
  }

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wesayforever.taimeitv_vip"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  signingConfigs {
    release {
      keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
      keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
      storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
      storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
    namespace 'com.wesayforever.shutiaotv_app'
}

flutter {
  source '../..'
}

dependencies {
  implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}

and this is the settings.gradle file:
    pluginManagement {
  def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
  }
  settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

  includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }
}

plugins {
  id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
  id "com.android.application" version '7.4.2' apply false
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

include ":app"

this is the androidmaniest file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>

    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
   <application
        android:label="泰美影视"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3261022732810553~9529490136"/>
    </application>
</manifest>


I tried disabling the R8 code obfuscation and resource shrinking, not working, add a flutter error listener in the main function, nothing printed.

Can you add the build.gradle, settings.gradle and manifest file in question.

@Ultranmus Sure, I have updated the question with these files included.
